# beginner error with IO monad and record syntax

Tags: haskell, io, monads

Here is a simplified version of my Code:

```
data Bookmark = Bookmark {
   url :: String
 , label :: String
 } deriving (Show)

genBookmark :: String -> String -> IO Bookmark
genBookmark u l = return ( Bookmark { url = u, label = l } )
```

But the Strings (url, label) are in the data base, so I have to deal with IO String. There must me a very easy solution, but I don't see it (and an extensive web search didn't get me anywhere.)

Basically I want to change my code to:

```
genBookmark :: IO String -> IO String -> IO Bookmark
```

Here is another version illustrating the problem:

```
genBookmark2 :: String -> String -> Bookmark
genBookmark2 u = return ( Bookmark { url = u, label = newlabel } )
                   where newlabel = getLine
```

With the error "Expected type: String, Actual type: IO String".

====== EDIT =======

Here is the "real code" that had the error (with the solution that I got from the answer):

```
getSkosConceptRight :: String -> IO SkosConcept
getSkosConceptRight catName = do
                      suConcepts <- getSubConcepts catName
                      concept <- getMainConcept catName 
                      return ( concept { subConcepts = suConcepts })

getSkosConceptWrong :: String -> IO SkosConcept
getSkosConceptWrong catName = return ( concept { subConcepts = suConcepts })
                        where suConcepts = getSubConcepts catName
                              concept = getMainConcept catName 

getMainConcept :: ShortUrl -> IO SkosConcept
getSubConcepts :: ShortUrl -> IO [SkosConcept]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've left out the part of your code that gets the string from the db.  Either way, you need to "unpack" the `String` from your `IO String`.

In general, you should get rid of the `IO` as early as possible.  So you should really try for a type of `String -> String -> Bookmark`

Here's a simple example:

```
-- These will represent your 'get from the db' calls
ioUrl :: IO String
ioUrl = return "http://..."

ioLabel :: IO String
ioLabel = return "my label"

genBookmark :: String -> String -> Bookmark
genBookmark url label = Bookmark { url = url, label = label }
```

Now, from `main` which is in `IO`, we make our "db" calls to get our strings, unpack the values, and send to our `genBookmark` function.

```
main = do
    url <- ioUrl     -- here, we're removing the "http://..." from the IO String
    label <- ioLabel -- same here
    print (genBookmark url label)
```

---

The reason why your `genBookmark2` is failing, is because you are trying to use `getLine`, whose type is `IO String` in a pure function; hence the `expected String, got IO String` error message.  Also, the type mentions two `String`s as inputs, but you only take one.

Comment: 1000 times thanks! From your answer I immediately saw the problem. I forgot to use the do notation in one function of my code. It's a snap servlet with db so I just posted the small code sample.

Comment: Note that genBookmark is rather pointless.  It does the same as Bookmark.